# Assigning a Back Slash character to java String

Tags: java, android, gson

I am trying to create a JSOn string from an object. My object has a field which holds date time of this format \/Date(1351598400000+0100)/ which I am storing as string.

Here is how I store this value to the object

```
sess.setTS_StartTime("\\\\/Date("+String.valueOf(appDeleg.getSessionDate())+"000+0100)"+"\\/");
```

I was expecting that this would return the required format mentioned above. But instead when converted to JSON using Google gson library I am getting back the exact string I stored. its not recognising any escape sequences.

This is what I get back as response in converted json string

```
\\\\/Date(1351684800000+0100)\\/
```

How can i do this properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

gson automatically escapes the json relevant characters of your string.

No need for manual escaping.